# WPF calling Result of async method causing block

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, prism

I have a WPF appplication using Prism and I have found a extrage behaviour with Async method.

I have a class with async methods like this

```
public class ConfigurationManager(){
    public async Task<IList<T>> LoadConfigurationAsync<T>(){
        Tuple<IList<T>, bool> tuple = await LoadConfigurationItemsAsync();
        return tuple.Item1;
    }

    private async Task<Tuple<IList<T>, bool>> LoadConfigurationItemsAsync<T>(){
        await Task.Run(()  => 
        {

        });
        return new Tuple<IList<T>, bool>(configList.list, succes);
    }
}
```

And I needed to call them in sync form because I need the results in constructor of ViewModelManager and I try to use Result because is one of the ways to get the result in sync way.

```
public class ViewModelManager{
    private readonly ConfigurationManager _configManager;

    private void LoadConfiguration(){
        var config = _configManager.LoadConfigurationAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

For my surprise this causes the application to get blocked in the Result call, I know that Result is blocking but not for always, the return line of the method never gets executed.
I tryed to call it using `Task.Run` and it works

```
private void LoadConfiguration(){
    var config = Task.Run(() => _configManager.LoadConfigurationAsync()).Result;
}
```

I don't know what's going on here and why calling result gets application blocked and why using `Task.Run` it works. It's like calling two tasks because the method is already returning a `Task`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can constructors be async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async)

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332872/c-sharp-async-deadlock/72349824#72349824 "C# Async deadlock") recent answer by Stephen Cleary, to a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing `.Result` is *always* a mistake (with a small caveat around "I've already checked that it has completed", with a secondary caveat about value-tasks and single access; honestly: the "always" is more useful advice than knowing the caveats!).

At the best case, you've achieved "sync over async" and tied up a thread for no good reason, impacting scalability and perhaps impacting the thread-pool.

However, if there's a synchronization context, you can - as you've found - deadlock things. A synchronization context acts as a work manager, and in the case of WPF: means *by default* funnelling callbacks and `await`s through the UI thread. So imagine:

- your UI thread runs, launches something in the background, then gets to the `.Result` and *waits* - not yet returning to the main app loop
- your background thing completes, and tries to signal a pending operation as complete, i.e. trigger the continuations that are associated with an `await` on that operation
- the `await` logic says "oh, I saw a sync-context - I need to push work via that" and adds something to the main app-loop

  - the thing being added to the app-loop is the thing that *tells the task that it is complete*, so that the `.Result` can finish
- boom: deadlock

Precisely because the UI thread is stuck on the `.Result`, the app-loop never gets to *actually mark the `.Result` as completed*. There are some ways of *improving* this with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, but the main intent of that is simply to avoid running things on the UI thread *when you wanted them to run in the background*; this approach shouldn't be used to prevent the deadlock, even if that happens to be a coincidental side-effect.

The "fix" here is simply: don't use `.Result` (or `.Wait()`). You need to `await` it, and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know the logic of async methods but sometimes I needed to run them in sync way and if it's true that calling .Result is not the best sometimes I do, but I have never seen a behaviour like this. For example in console application this doesn't cause problems.
If I understand well this bahaviour is caused because I have blocked the UI thread and it has no option to mark as completed the task calling .Result. Why calling via Task.Run works, I'm also calling result there? I asked it the case here to have better comprehenssion and learn more

Comment: @JuanDYB a console application is very different from a gui application, async-wait-wise. Stephen Cleary's [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) is good read to get you started.

Comment: @JuanDYB "For example in console application this doesn't cause problems" - yup; console applications *don't have a sync-context*, i.e. they don't have a UI thread and application loop. That doesn't mean it was ever OK to call `.Result` - just: you *got away with doing something inadvisable*. It was still inadvisable.