# .NET MAUI App Crashes on Navigating to a Page with Data Binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

**Question :**
I've encountered a puzzling issue with my .NET MAUI app, and I'm hoping the community can help me pinpoint the problem. When I navigate to a specific page in my app, it becomes unresponsive. I've spent hours debugging, but I can't seem to find the root cause.
**Problem Description :**
I have a .NET MAUI app with several pages, including a ProductPage and a CreateProductPage. The ProductPage displays a list of products using data binding, and the CreateProductPage allows users to create new products.

Here's the problem:

1. When I navigate to the ProductPage, everything works perfectly. The list of products is displayed correctly.
2. However, when I navigate to the CreateProductPage, the app  becomes unresponsive and doesn't recover.

**Code Samples:**
Here are snippets of the XAML and code-behind for CreateProductPage:
CreateProductPage XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MarjaneStock.Maui.CreateProductPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MarjaneStock.Maui.ViewModels"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:MarjaneStock.Maui.CustomControls"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MarjaneStock.Maui.Controls"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MarjaneStock.Maui.Models"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:CreateProductPageViewModel"
             Title="CreateProductPage"
             Padding="0">
    <ScrollView Padding="0"
                Margin="0">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="80,*"
              Padding="0"
              Margin="0">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions=".1*,.9*"
                  BackgroundColor="#0b4c90"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10">
                    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Text="&#xE803;"
                            FontFamily="Icons"
                            FontSize="27"
                            TextColor="#FEE800"
                            BorderWidth="0"
                            Command="{Binding ReturnCommand}"/>
                    <Label Text="Back"
                           TextColor="#FEE800"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           FontSize="27"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="Create Product"
                       TextColor="#FEE800"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontSize="27"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Scale="1.5"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                  RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*"
                  Padding="15,0"
                  Margin="0">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="50"
                      VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Frame Padding="1"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           MinimumWidthRequest="800"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           MaximumWidthRequest="800"
                           BorderColor="#0b4c90"
                           CornerRadius="20">
                        <Entry BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                               MinimumWidthRequest="800"
                               MaximumWidthRequest="800"
                               FontSize="18"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
                    </Frame>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           FontSize="21"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           Text="Name : "
                           TranslationY="-40"
                           TextColor="#0b4c90"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="50"
                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                      Grid.Row="1">
                    <Frame Padding="1"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           MinimumWidthRequest="800"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           MaximumWidthRequest="800"
                           BorderColor="#0b4c90"
                           CornerRadius="20">
                        <Entry BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                               MinimumWidthRequest="800"
                               MaximumWidthRequest="800"
                               FontSize="18"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding UnitPrice}"/>
                    </Frame>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           FontSize="21"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           Text="Unit Price : "
                           TranslationY="-40"
                           TextColor="#0b4c90"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="50"
                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                      Grid.Row="2">
                    <Frame Padding="1"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           MinimumWidthRequest="800"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           MaximumWidthRequest="800"
                           BorderColor="#0b4c90"
                           CornerRadius="20">
                        <Entry BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                               MinimumWidthRequest="800"
                               MaximumWidthRequest="800"
                               FontSize="18"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding PackageQuantity}"/>
                    </Frame>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           FontSize="21"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           Text="Quantity Per Package : "
                           TranslationY="-40"
                           TextColor="#0b4c90"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                </Grid>
                <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="3"
                                     Margin="0"
                                     Padding="0"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Select a Section : "
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="20"
                           TextColor="#0B4C90"
                           Padding="0"
                           Margin="0"/>
                    <Border WidthRequest="800"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            Stroke="#0B4C90"
                            StrokeThickness="3"
                            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5,5,5,5"
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFF">
                        <Picker WidthRequest="800"
                                HeightRequest="50"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding SectionName}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection}"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">
                        </Picker>
                    </Border>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="4"
                                     Margin="0"
                                     Padding="0"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Select a Supplier : "
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="20"
                           TextColor="#0B4C90"
                           Padding="0"
                           Margin="0"/>
                    <Border WidthRequest="800"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            Stroke="#0B4C90"
                            StrokeThickness="3"
                            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5,5,5,5"
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFF">
                        <Picker WidthRequest="800"
                                HeightRequest="50"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Suppliers}"
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding SupplierName}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSupplier}"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">
                        </Picker>
                    </Border>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <Button Grid.Row="5"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="400"
                        CornerRadius="20"
                        BackgroundColor="#0B4C90"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Text="Create Product"
                        TextColor="#FEE800"
                        FontSize="20"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        Command="{Binding CreateProductCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

CreateProductPage Code-Behind:

```
using MarjaneStock.Maui.Services;
using MarjaneStock.Maui.ViewModels;

namespace MarjaneStock.Maui;

public partial class CreateProductPage : ContentPage
{
    public CreateProductPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext =new CreateProductPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

CreateProductPageViewModel :

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MarjaneStock.Maui.DTO;
using MarjaneStock.Maui.Models;
using MarjaneStock.Maui.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MarjaneStock.Maui.ViewModels;

public partial class CreateProductPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    public async void Return()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///"+nameof(ProductPage));
    }

    private Rayon _selectedSection;
    public Rayon SelectedSection
    {
        get => _selectedSection;
        set
        {
            _selectedSection = value;
        }
    }

    private Supplier _selectedSupplier;
    public Supplier SelectedSupplier
    {
        get => _selectedSupplier;
        set
        {
            _selectedSupplier = value;
        }
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string productName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public double unitPrice;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public int packageQuantity;

    public ObservableCollection<Rayon> Sections { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Rayon>();

    public ObservableCollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Supplier>();
    public CreateProductPageViewModel()
    {
        GetSectionsList();
        GetSuppliersList();
    }

    private async void GetSectionsList()
    {
        var sectionList = new List<Rayon>();

        var sectionUrl = "https://localhost:7282/api/Sections/GetSections";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var Apiresponse = await client.GetAsync(sectionUrl);

            if (Apiresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var content = await Apiresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                sectionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rayon>>(content);
            }

        }

        if(sectionList?.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(var section in sectionList)
            {
                Sections.Add(section);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void GetSuppliersList()
    {
        var supplierList = new List<Supplier>();

        var supplierUrl = "https://localhost:7282/api/SupliersContoller/GetSuppliers";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var Apiresponse = await client.GetAsync(supplierUrl);

            if (Apiresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var content = await Apiresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                supplierList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Supplier>>(content);
            }
        }

        if (supplierList?.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(var supplier in supplierList)
            {
                Suppliers.Add(supplier);
            }
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task CreateProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            // Validate that required data is entered (you can add more validation)
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductName) || SelectedSection == null || SelectedSupplier == null)
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "No field Should be Empty", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            // Create a ProductDto from user-entered data
            var productDto = new ProductDto
            {
                ProductName = ProductName,
                UnitPrice = UnitPrice,
                PackageQuantity = PackageQuantity,
                SectionId = SelectedSection.Id,
                SupplierId = SelectedSupplier.Id
            };

            // Serialize the ProductDto to JSON
            var productJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productDto);

            // Send a POST request to your API to create the product
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Replace with the actual URL for your API
                string apiUrl = "https://localhost:7282/api/Products/CreateProduct";

                // Set the content type
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Send the POST request with the serialized JSON data
                var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(productJson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried several debugging steps, including:

- Checking the XAML and code-behind for both ProductPage and CreateProductPage for any issues in data bindings or other logic.
- Adding exception handling to catch any unhandled exceptions, but no exceptions are thrown.
- Placing breakpoints in the navigation command that takes me to CreateProductPage:
  `[RelayCommand] public async void AddProduct() {await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(CreateProductPage));}`
  , but it never reaches there. The app crashes before that.
  **Additional Information :**
- I'm using .NET MAUI with Visual Studio.
- All my dependencies are up to date.
  Can someone please help me identify the problem or suggest steps to further diagnose this issue? I'm open to any insights or ideas on what might be causing the app to crash when navigating to CreateProductPage.

Comment: Xamarin and MAUI are different things.  Crashing and “unresponsive” are also two different things.  That said, you are calling async methods from the constructor without await.  This is a well known path to creating a deadlock

Comment: `Placing breakpoints in the navigation command that takes me to CreateProductPage, but it never reaches there. The app crashes before that.`  Are you saying that before navigating to `CreateProductPage`, the code is unresponsive? Could you please post the code of navigating code before navigating to `CreateProductPage`?

Comment: Based on the code you shared, I created a new demo and added some fake data to `CreateProductPageViewModel `, but there is no problem on page `CreateProductPage`. So you can recheck the code of navigating to page `CreateProductPage`? In addition, you can also try to debug step by step to find the detail of this problem.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT yes i meant that the app doesn't respond anymore before navigating to the CreateProductPage (specifically when i click a butto in the page before to navigate to the CreateProductPage).Here's the navigation code that i use in the page before . `public async void AddProduct(){ await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(CreateProductPage));} . I aslo tried sureounding this navigation code with try catch to see the exception but whenever i use debugging mode and put breakpoints on this method it doesn't even access it and asks me to rebuild the app to apply changes

Comment: I've [added an answer specific to MVVM UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77078003/199364) on the "C# Async Deadlock" thread that this is question is marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i've tried your solution and it works better than i expected thank you so much