# How to fix the problem of the object passed while navigating does not contain any data in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

So i was working on this project when i needed to pass the id of a Section and then capture it in another page called 'SelectSupplierPage' and then use this object to preform an api call to display some data on appearing but when i see the content of that object i find always that it is null so i tried to replace that object whit an int represanting the id (which all i need to pass around) but i always find it equals to 0 also .
Here is the View Model of the SelectSupplierPage (the one that i navigate to) :

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(SectionId),"SectionId")]
    public partial class SelectSupplierPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    int sectionId;
        public int SectionId
        {
            get => sectionId;
            set
            {
                sectionId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Supplier> _suppliers;

        public ObservableCollection<Supplier> Suppliers
        {
            get => _suppliers; // Bind to the filtered collection
            set => SetProperty(ref _suppliers, value);
        }

        public static async Task<SelectSupplierPageViewModel> Create()
        {
            var it = new SelectSupplierPageViewModel();
            await it.Initialize();
            return it;
        }

        private async Task Initialize()
        {
            await GetuppliersList();
        }

        public SelectSupplierPageViewModel()
        {
            Suppliers = new ObservableCollection<Supplier>();
        }

        public async Task GetuppliersList()
        {
            var supplierList = new List<Supplier>();

            var supplierUrl = $"https://localhost:7282/api/SectionSupliers/GetSuppliersInSection/{SectionId}";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var Apiresponse = await client.GetAsync(supplierUrl);

                if (Apiresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var content = await Apiresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    supplierList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Supplier>>(content);
                }

            }

            if (supplierList?.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var section in supplierList)
                {
                    Suppliers.Add(section);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And here is the code behind (SelectSupplierPage.xaml.cs) :

```
public SelectSupplierPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private bool isInitialized;

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            isInitialized = true;
            await SetBindingContext();
        }
    }

    private async Task SetBindingContext()
    {
        var vm = await SelectSupplierPageViewModel.Create();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
```

And finally here is the command i use to navigate from the first page to the SelectSupplierPage :

```
public ICommand SelectSectionCommand => new Command<Rayon>(SelectSection);

        public async void SelectSection(Rayon section)
        {
            //await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Test", $"Id {section.Id}", "ok");
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(SelectSupplierPage)}?SectionId={section.Id}");
        }
```

I need to mention that before i try to call the api i binded the content of the object to a label (before i changed it to the SectionId parameter) just for testing purposes and it worked perfectly but when i added the methods Create , Initialize , GetupplierList and altered the code-behind it just stoped working as the parameter passed didn't contain any value although when i use debugging mode in the command that allows me tonavigate i find that the id has a value .

Comment: Let me guess, you have read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332872/c-sharp-async-deadlock/77078003#77078003? It is not the right way. All this deadlock non-sense is resolved by following one simple rule - do not make heavy api calls in your constructors. Manually constructing - NO. All the ViewModels are constructed and injected when and if needed. There is nothing wrong in setting your ViewModels in the page creation, and your Services during ViewModel creation.

Comment: Non-related to the above - there is no such thing as private ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would have done it, assuming I have `SomePage` and `SomeViewModel`

First we register them in MauiProgram.cs using `builder.Services.AddTransient`.

Why transient? Because we are using Shell.

Second, we go to SomePage.xaml.cs and we modify the constructor:

```
public SomePage(SomeViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
}
```

Done. That's it. When the Shell navigates to the page, the dependency injection will make that ViewModel and pass it to the constructor. No more actions are needed.

Now we move to the ViewModel, that looks like this:

```
public partial class SomeViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
```

And we implement the interface IQueryAttributable:

```
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
{
    SomeData = query[nameof(SomeData)] as SomeData;
}
```

And last, when we navigate to there:

```
Dictionary<string, object> query = new()
{
     { nameof(SomeData), data}
};
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(SomePage)}", query);
```

You can match the Type or the Property, the important thing is the key to be the same.

Done. Do you see me using the word "new" anywhere? This is the way.

Comment: I just want to ask you the IQueryAttributable should i implement it in the view model of the page that i want to navigate to oe the page that i want to navigate from ??

Comment: @YassineElmesbahy yes, you implement it in the ViewModel, that is set as BindingContext of the page you are navigating TO. I find implementing it better, than using annotations. For more than one reason.